# Oracle - SQL Query to return a value from a column in another table where value equals a different column

Tags: sql, oracle

From within the results of a query I need to take the first 3 digits (got this part - substr) from a column in one table and pull the value from a second table where the 3 digit code is in a different column of the same row.  While I'm not looking for assistance in this part I will be grouping by the code column for reference

```
    Example
    Table 1        Table 2
    3_Digit        Code_Column    Description
    123456         123            Blue
    103456         103            Green
```

so if my substr query return 123 5 times I'm looking for

```
    Blue 3
```

Comment: Sorry my formatting got changed.    Table 1 Column: Row 1:123456, Row 2 103456.   Table 2 Column 1:  3 Digit Code,  Table 2 Column 2: Description

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t2.Code_Column, count(*)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on  substr(t1.digit, 0, 3) = t2.Code_Column
group by t2.Code_Column
```

[**SQL Fiddle sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a122a/3/0)